# PHP scandir explorer view to display network share files (file://) via WAMP. Works on localhost but not by IP address

Tags: php, file-io, localhost, external, wamp

Maybe I am being daft, or misunderstanding either WAMP restrictions or browser restrictions, but I have created a PHP file explorer view using the scandir function recursively using Ajax, and it works great to display the files from our network share (\computername\share).

I can launch the files when accessing http://localhost, however if from the same localhost machine I access http://[our_external_ip_address] then the files do not open. The path in the status bar displays the same on both (e.g. file://computername/share/filename.zip). I eventually want to put the files on a network share which is on the same domain as our web host machine.

Please help. I am fairly competent with PHP & JS but when it comes to web hosts and the like, I am stuffed. TIA.

James

Comment: I would say that the best approach here would be to create a file-read proxy with PHP, so that all links are `http://`, and PHP `readfile()`s the file when they are accessed. It will be more reliable and more portable overall. Is there some reason you can't/don't want to do this?

Comment: Maybe I was overstating when I said fairly competent with PHP :) I haven't used readfile but I have published download files with the object buffers for images. I was keen to get the PDF files to open using the integrated browser feature but even better would be a preview plugin that displays PDF's and Word files similar to that of the image slider jquery plugins.

Comment: I have managed to have limited success with external users and internal users able to access cross domain downloads by using right-click save target as. However, click to open in new tab is not working.

Comment: As for the read-file proxy we do have something similar setup, and we put files in their for external clients to access using IIS. This is a mapped drive on our domain so its fairly easy to drag/drop but ideally it would be in an non-hosted domain share within the normal directory structure of our file server. The only reason for this is that some of the folders may be distributed around a bit, from other departments e.t.c and the purposes of this app is to consolidate the diverse information we have.

Comment: The long of the short of this is that PHP support for accessing SMB shares, mapped network drives or UNC, is flakey at best. But I definitely think that you should aim to design this in such a way that the PHP script proxies *all* the data exchanges, so that everything is done over HTTP to the client. If you can successfully `scandir()`, you should be able to `readfile()`, `fopen()` etc. You can still let the browser handle things such as native PDF viewers as long as you send the correct `Content-Type:` header for the file. This is a little long-winded to reasonably answer here.

Comment: We will be happy to help you get this set up - but what you need to do is try and write it yourself, and come back with more specific problems and code samples.

Comment: This is a fantastic starting point for me. I've managed to do some nice embedding with the plugin "pdfobject" but it still cannot grab the file directly it seems. I have been doing a lot of research around this, however as you mentioned I will need to investigate readfile() a lot more I think to get server-side to handle the local file grab. Thanks so much for your help. :)

Comment: Sorted using readfile() read-proxy as you stated. I will post solution shortly. Could you confirm if there is a way to detect if PDF or DOC viewers are available as otherwise it attempts to download my filehandler.php proxy script. I handle different mime types by extension evaluation.

Comment: There is no way to detect how the browser will handle the content, *however*... What you need to do is send the correct `Content-Type:` header (e.g. `application/pdf` for PDF files), and a `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="<file_name>"` header, where `<file_name>` is the name of the file. This will cause the browser, in the event that it has no viewer configured, to present the file download with the correct file name. Note `inline`, not `attachment` as you may be used to - this tells the browser to render the content if it can, not force a download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massive thanks to DaveRandom - this solution worked to allow PDF / Word / Zip files from a UNC path to be launched from an external web client.

**FILE 1: - index.php**

```
<?php
    $filename= *** insert UNC path to file *** // e.g. \\share\computername\New Document.doc
    $extension= pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // Gets extension for file
    $displayFilename= *** insert shorten filename *** // e.g. New Document.doc
?>


<a href="filehandler.php?name=<?php echo $filename; ?>&ext=<?php echo $extension; ?>&shortname=<?php echo $displayFilename; ?>"><?php echo $displayFilename; ?></a>
```

**FILE 2: - filehandler.php**

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['name'];
$extension = $_GET['ext'];
$shortfilename = $_GET['shortname'];
if ($extension == "pdf")
{
    header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // act as a pdf file to browser
}
if ($extension == "doc")
{
    header("Content-type: application/msword"); // act as a doc file to browser
}
if ($extension == "zip")
{
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); // act as a zip file to browser
}
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename='$shortfilename'"); 

$file = readfile($filename);
echo $file;
?>
```